# Show all nested menu links in Drupal 7

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

How do I display all nested links in `<ul><li>` format in Drupal 7? The default code only displays the 1st level links even though they are arranged in the Drupal admin menu as nested:

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
<div id="mainmenu"> <?php print theme( 'links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu) ); ?> </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Only the 1st level is displayed in the ff. menu setup:

```
-Fruits
---Apples
---Oranges
---Lemons
-Cars
---Big car
---Small car
---Fucked up car
-Whatever
```

Comment: Also there is a menu_block module which allows creating arbitrary amount of customized blocks showing needed portions of menu

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default `$main_menu` variable in `page.tpl.php` is set to [`menu_main_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_main_menu/7), which is a contextual view of the main menu tree.

To get your desired output, you need to get the entire menu tree using [`menu_tree_all_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7) and [`menu_tree_output()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_output/7).

To do this in your theme, create `template.php` if you haven't already, and add a new preprocess function for the page template:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Get the entire main menu tree
  $main_menu_tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');

  // Add the rendered output to the $main_menu_expanded variable
  $variables['main_menu_expanded'] = menu_tree_output($main_menu_tree);
}
```

Then, in `page.tpl.php`, you can just use:

```
<?php print render($main_menu_expanded); ?>
```

to get a expanded, nested unordered list of the main menu.

For a little more flexibility, you might want to consider the [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module, which will let you create blocks of expanded menus out of the box with its *Expand all children of this tree* option as well as a host of other options for segmenting menu trees.