# Showing nested links in Drupal but still add classes to list elements

Tags: routes, navigation

Very new to Drupal and a bit confused.

In order to render a menu in my theme I've been using this:

```
print theme('links', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links'))));
```

That works a treat and gives me an extra class on the first and last list items, which I need for styling. It doesn't, however, show any of the nested sub menus.
So I found this that again, worked like a charm [Show all nested menu links in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/show-all-nested-menu-links-in-drupal-7) and shows all the top-level links in the main menu and the nested ones too.
This doesn't give me the extra classes on the first and last list items which I need.
Is there any way to use the code from the answer above and give the extra classes on the list items?

Thanks muchly

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.
>
> You should use this module when
>
> - You want to "nofollow" certain menu items to sculpt the flow of PageRank through your site
> - You want to give a menu item an ID so you can easily select it using jQuery
> - You want to add additional classes or styles to a menu item

Comment: Boom!
Nice one fella. Just what I needed.
If I had some rep, I'd up-vote you......

Comment: I did it for you.

Comment: Cheers SpaceBeers. Top name btw.